# Translate simple formal grammar to vim syntax

Tags: vim, syntax, grammar, bison

I want to write `bison` syntax file for `vim`. I've managed to write syntax rule for definition section. Now I'm trying to compose syntax rule for `bison` rule. So, I have

```
rule : identifier ":" rightHandSidePart ( "|" rightHandSidePart )* ";"
```

where

```
rightHandSidePart : listOfIdentifiers "{" /* some C code here */ "}"
listOfIdentifiers : listOfIdentifiers identifier | /* nothing */
```

and `identifier` may be declared as `[_a-zA-Z][_0-9a-zA-Z]*` regular expression.
So the question is: how do I translate this grammar to vim syntax rules?

Comment: Can't you just use the yacc syntax file?

Comment: @sidyll, i've used it, but it lacks support of `bison`-specific keywords and blocks. Now i'm adjusting built-in yacc syntax file, but this one is a mess, so i ended up rewriting it entirely

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [autohighlight](https://code.google.com/p/autohighlight/) to convert your grammar to vim's syntax regex.

> Autohighlight generates vim and emacs syntax highlighting from a BNF grammar and a description of which terms should be highlighted which colors.